# sed command to delete two subsequent lines in a file

Tags: design-patterns, sed, lines

My file contains lines like

```
GRANT SELECT ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
/
GRANT INSERT ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
/
GRANT UPDATE ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
/
GRANT DELETE ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
/
GRANT SELECT ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER2
/
GRANT INSERT ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER2
/
GRANT UPDATE ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER2
```

... and so on ...

The sed command I'm seeking, or better, the pattern, that crosses two lines,
should delete the "GRANT .." line plus the subsequent line that's starting with the "/".

Any solutions from you sed gurus?

Comment: When creating sample input to demonstrate your regexp needs, it's a good idea to include lines that you do NOT want to match the regexp as it's always trivial to come up with a script that matches the lines you want (e.g. `.*` will usually do it!) but much harder to write a script that will NOT match the lines you don't want. Right now we're all guessing about what should be done when the `GRANT` line is not immediately followed by a `/` line. And remember to show your desired output - sample input is much less useful without that!

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/^GRANT/ { N; d }' filename
```

will, when it encounters a line beginning with `GRANT`, fetch the next line and discard both.

To only remove `GRANT` lines when the next line begins with `/`,

```
sed ':a /^GRANT/ { N; /\n\//! { P; s/.*\n//; ba }; d }' filename
```

works. This is complicated mostly because of the possibility that two `GRANT` lines come directly one after another, as in

```
GRANT foo
GRANT bar
/
```

where `GRANT bar` and `/` have to be removed and `GRANT foo` to remain untouched:

```
:a            # jump label for looping
/^GRANT/ {    # if a line begins with GRANT
  N           # fetch the next line
  /\n\//! {   # if the next line does not begin with /
    P         # print the first
    s/.*\n//  # remove it
    ba        # go back to :a
  }
  d           # otherwise discard both
}
```

Alternatively, using a multiline regex after reading the file completely into memory (assuming it fits there):

```
sed ':a $!{N; ba}; s/\(^\|\n\)GRANT[^\n]*\n\/[^\n]*//g' filename
```

where

```
:a $!{N; ba}                          # read whole file into the pattern space
 s/\(^\|\n\)GRANT[^\n]*\n\/[^\n]*//g  # match offending lines by regex and
                                      # remove them
```

At this point, however, I feel that the sanest option is to use `pcregrep` in muiltiline mode:

```
pcregrep -vM '^GRANT[^\n]*\n/' filename
```

Comment: That's fine and would suffice in my case. Would there be an alternative in the way that a regex is created that contains the newline in its pattern (to be more flexible?

Comment: A common way to have multiline regexes in `sed` is to read the file completely into memory before working on it. In this case, for example: `:a $!{N; ba}; s/\(^\|\n\)GRANT[^\n]*\n\/[^\n]*//g` (the regex is untested). However, to exclude lines based on a multiline regex, I'd probably use `pcregrep -vM regex filename` -- in this case `pcregrep -vM '^GRANT[^\n]*\n/' filename`.

Comment: This does not delete next line starting with `/ ` after `GRANT`, it deletes any line after  `GRANT`

Comment: @Jotne OP has a file where every line after a `GRANT` begins with `/`. I added a few more careful variations, anyway, although it's unclear what should happen if a `/` line is missing for reasons. These variations leave the `GRANT` line in such a case, purely on the basis that removing things by guesswork is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk '/^GRANT/ {f=1;next} f && /^\// {f=0;next} 1' file
```

If the line starting with `^GRANT`, skip it and set flag `f` to true.
If line starts with `/` and flag `f` is true, skip it and reset flag  `f`
`1` print all other lines.

So this will only delete lines starting with `GRANT` and the next line starting with  `/`

Example:

```
cat file
GRANT SELECT ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
/
GRANT INSERT ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
test
/ should be removed
some other data
/ should not be removed
GRANT UPDATE ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
/
GRANT DELETE ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
/
GRANT SELECT ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER2
/
GRANT INSERT ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER2
/
GRANT UPDATE ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER2
```

```
awk '/GRANT/ {f=1;next} f && /^\// {f=0;next} 1' file
test
some other data
/ should not be removed
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is for operations on single lines. For anything that spans lines you should use awk. e.g. with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/GRANT[^\n]+\n[/]\n/,"")}1' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
foo
GRANT INSERT ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
/
GRANT UPDATE ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
intermediate line so leave
/
GRANT DELETE ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
/
bar

$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/GRANT[^\n]+\n[/]\n/,"")}1' file
foo
GRANT UPDATE ON USER.TABLE1 TO USER1
intermediate line so leave
/
bar
```